# Reference for PDE problem book

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, textbook-recommendation

What I need is a source of solved exercises, problems in Partial Differential Equations; to be hard enough (olympiad style) and in areas like Calderon-Zygmund theory and applications, Paley-Littlewood decomposition, Strichartz, Wave eq. etc., but not so difficult as the celebrated theorems in the field (I do not want numerical direct applications). (I know Tao's book but some of the exercises are too hard and unmotivating and the other ones are too easy.)
Thank in advance.

Comment: Here are a few: http://msp.org/apde/about/cover/cover.html has quite a lot, http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/lpde20/current you have to dig a bit more, ditto http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-differential-equations ; the ones in http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/proc are almost always short and easy to read, with extremely beautiful ideas, but recently there are fewer in the fields you specified.

Comment: BTW, I am being only partially facetious. If _my student_ comes to me asking for suggestions for "solved exercises" in the fields you mention, that's how I would answer. // I also don't understand this "Olympiad style" qualification: mathematics Olympiads typically have zero PDE/harmonic analysis content. What exactly is it that you are hoping to achieve by solving a bunch of easy, but not too easy exercises?

Comment: Is this "Partial Differential Equations: Graduate Level Problems
and Solutions by
IgorYanovsky" kown to you ? Is it as hard as you would like ?

Comment: @WillieWong thank you for these links.